# Get out other users with same PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have powershell question

Iam trying to get out one users PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName and then use it so search after other users with the same PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName

```
Get-ADUser Tom -properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | select PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
```

Now i want use the Tom's PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName to search after other users with the same PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter “(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=California)" | select GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName | Format-list GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName
```

It works just the way i want to.

if i do it like this, it also works

```
$Office = "California"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter “(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=$Office)" | select GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName | Format-list GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName
```

But i do it like this it does not work at all

```
$user = Get-ADUser Tom -properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | select PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | out-string    

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter “(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=$user)" | select GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName | Format-list GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName
```

I would really like to know how to draw the other users in the same office by using the last example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$user = Get-ADUser Tom -properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | Select -ExpandProperty PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
```

What you were doing was resulting in $user containing the Format-Table view of the property you wanted (e.g a multi-line string with a header), where as by using the `-ExpandProperty` parameter the value of that property gets returned as an object of that type (e.g String in this case).